# Linking two objects to a single record in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm trying to make two one to one relationships in the same class in rails.

I added two columns to my class called link

post_id1
post_id2

So now I want to be able to get a link object, and do

```
link.post1

link.post2
```

But I'm getting confused about how to specify this

I assume it's something to do with

```
has_one :Post, => specify name so the references don't clash
```

I assume this is really easy, I'm just new to rails.

Answer (score 1):

You will need post1_id and post2_id in links table and:

```
belongs_to :post1, class_name: "Post"
belongs_to :post2, class_name: "Post"
```

In the Post model you can use has_one or has_many for back reference.

UPDATE:
Here is a reference for this: [choosing between belongs_to and has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs_to-and-has_one)

Answer (score 1):

The other answered helped me, but it was also this I was specifically looking for

```
:foreign_key => "post_id1"
```

So the final line is

```
belongs_to :post_1, :class => "Post", :foreign_key => "post_id1"
```

Thanks for your help too!

Answer (score 0):

In class `Link`:

```
belongs_to :post_1, :class => "Post"
belongs_to :post_2, :class => "Post"
```

EDIT: [corrected `belongs_to`]

Comment: The other points moved me in the right direction, but I also needed to specify the column that held the key